# Multiple @WebsocketGatways, life cycle hook is called multiple times for each connection

Tags: nestjs

I have multiple `@WebsocketGateways` in my project, one implementing the `OnGatewayConnection` life cycle hook. It seems like the life cycle hook is called once for each Gateway, even though only one is implementing them. Is this the default behavior, a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**CommonGateway**

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class CommonGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  @WebSocketServer() server;
  users: number = 0;

  handleConnection() {
    this.users++;

    console.log('USER CONNECTED: ', this.users);
  }

  handleDisconnect() {
    this.users--;

    console.log('USER Disconnected: ', this.users);
  }
}
```

**DatesGateway**

```
import {
  WebSocketGateway,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WsResponse,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { CommonService } from 'src/common/common.service';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class DatesGateway {
  constructor(private readonly commonService: CommonService) {}

  @SubscribeMessage('dates-now')
  onNow(client): Promise<WsResponse<Date>> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.commonService.now).then(now => ({
      event: 'dates-now',
      data: now,
    }));
  }
}
```

**Console screenshot**

[image]

A small repo demonstrating the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/KenavR/nest-websocket-gateway-issue)

thanks

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Found a solution myself. Posted it below

Answer (score 3):

## Update

This was [fixed](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3704#issuecomment-569259021) in **6.10.13**.

Kamil's [guidance](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/126#issuecomment-341832752) to leave the `@WebSocketGateway` decorator empty now applies in the case where you have multiple WebSocket gateways (and wish to avoid `handleConnection` being called multiple times).

---

### Pre v6.10.13

I just encountered this issue after creating several gateways. I'm using version **6.10.1** of `@nestjs/platform-ws` and `@nestjs/websockets`.

With the solution below, a single WebSocket server will be created and `handleConnection` will be called once (as desired). The `handleDisconnect` event always (correctly) fired once. It is important to note that:

1. A namespace must be included when defining the gateway.

   - When using the `platform-ws` adapter the namespaces can be either unique or identical.
   - When using the `platform-socket.io` adapter the namespaces must be identical.
2. A port must be included when defining the gateway. The ports should be identical **but** different from the HTTP server port to avoid `EADDRINUSE` and `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The HTTP/S server is already being used by another WebSocket server` errors.
3. If you create many gateways you may see the `MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit` warning. I still need to look into this.

**app.gateway.ts**

```
@WebSocketGateway(8080, {namespace: 'foo'})
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  constructor() {}

  public handleConnection(): void {}

  public handleDisconnect(): void {}

  @SubscribeMessage('app:event')
  public handleGet(): WsResponse<string> {
    return {
      event: 'app:event',
      data: 'foobar'
    };
  }
}
```

**user.gateway.ts**

```
@WebSocketGateway(8080, {namespace: 'foo'})
export class UserGateway {
  constructor() {}

  @SubscribeMessage('user:event')
  public handleGet(): WsResponse<string> {
    return {
      event: 'user:event',
      data: 'foobar'
    };
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
  await app.listen(80);
}
bootstrap();
```

More insight into this would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks you works ey spent all day on this

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. 
Obviously it is a bug (?) in NestJS that it initiates multiple namespaces for all of your Gateways if you dont define any namespace at all. Then for each is a connection event.

The solution is to define the same namespace on each of your `WebSocketGateways`

```
@WebSocketGateway({namespace: 'yournamespace'})
```

And connect to the server in the client like so:

```
io.connect('http://localhost:4200/yournamespace');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared the gateway multiple times in modules instead of declaring it as an export in the main module and importing it in another. I also had a similar problem and found either removing an exporting or setting your module as a global decorator module helped. Please research the global decorator for the module before proceeding to use it: https://docs.nestjs.com/modules